# Integers that are power of a fixed integer mod every prime

Tags: number-theory

If $a,b \in \mathbb Z$ and the following property holds:

For every prime p in $\mathbb Z$, there exists an integer $n_p$ such that $b \equiv a^{n_p} \operatorname{mod} p $

Then can we deduce that there exists an integer n such that $b=a^n$?

Comment: For related work see  N. Jones, [A logcal-global principle for power maps, 2014](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.1946) $\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

First I prove the claim when $a$ and $b$ are positive.

To do this the first step is to prove by contradiction that $a^s = b^t$ for some integers $s,t$.

Suppose not. Then there are two primes $p$ and $q$ such that $v_p(a)v_q(b) \neq v_q(a)v_p(b)$.

Pick a prime $k$ large enough such that $a$ and $b$ are not $k$th powers and $v_p(a)v_q(b) \neq v_q(a)v_p(b) \pmod k$, and finally look at the primes $l$ congruent to $1$ mod $k$.

Since $a$ and $b$ are not $k$th powers, they are a $k$th power modulo $l$ around $1/k$ of the time (thanks to the Cebotarev density theorem).
However, your hypothesis implies that if $a$ is a $k$th power modulo $l$, then so is $b$. And so the primes $l$ that split in the Galois closure of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[k]b)$ must be almost exactly the primes that split in the Galois closure of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[k]a)$ (in fact, with a finite number of exception but you need slightly deeper stuff to prove it)

Still with the Cebotarev density theorem, we can then deduce that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[k]a) = \Bbb Q(\sqrt[k]b)$, and then that one among $b/a, b/a^2, \ldots b/a^{k-1}$ is a $k$th power.

But this contradicts $v_p(a)v_q(b) \neq v_q(a)v_p(b) \pmod k$

---

Now we can assume that $a^s = b^t$, where $s$ and $t$ are coprime.

Suppose $t \neq 1$. if $p$ divides $t$, then $a^s$ is a $p$th power, and so $a$ is also a $p$th power (because $p$ doesn't divide $s$), and so it is a $p$th power modulo every prime $l$. With your hypothesis we get that $b$ is also a $p$th power modulo every prime, which is enough to deduce that $b$ is a $p$th power. But then $a$ becomes a $p^2$th power, and then so does $b$ etc. This implies $a=b=1$, and we are done.

If $t = 1$ then we have $b=a^s$ and we are also done.

---

Now I prove the more general case with $a,b \in \Bbb Z$.

The case where $a$ or $b$ is zero is immediate.

If not then we look at $a^2$ and $b^2$.

If $b=a^{n_p} \pmod p$, then $b^2 = (a^2)^{n_p} \pmod p$, and so $a^2$ and $b^2$ still satisfy the hypothesis, and are positive, so we can apply the result we have just proven to them to get that $b^2 = (a^2)^s$ for some $s$.

Then $b = a^s$ or $b= -a^s$.

If $b= -a^s$ then $-1 = a^{n_p-s} \pmod p$ forall $p$ not dividing $a$. Let $p$ be a prime dividing $a-1$. Then $-1 = 1 \pmod p$ and so $p=2$. Also, $a$ can be a square mod $p$ only when $-1$ is, which means that $-a$ is a square, which leaves $a=-1$ as the only possibility (if $a = (-2^k)+1 = -c^2$ then $2^k = c^2+1 = 1,2 \pmod 4$ so $k=0$ or $k=1$).
Then $b = -a^s = a(a^s) = a^{s+1}$ is still a power of $a$.

Comment: It's a good answer, but I don't understand some parts: Firstly, why x^k-a has a root mod p is equivalent to that p splits complety in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[k]a)$ as I think we can only see that f(P|p)=1 for some P but not for all P in the non-Galois case. Secondly, how can we deduce from \Bbb Q(\sqrt[k]a) = \Bbb Q(\sqrt[k]b) that  one in b/a,b/a^2,…,b/a^{k−1} is a kth power? (the case of k=2 is already tedious). Last, Why the splitting primes are exactly the same as I don't know whether the degree of Galois closures are the same. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: $x^k-a$ splits completely iff there is a $k$th root of $1$ and a $k$th root of $a$ in $\Bbb F_p$. Since I'm only looking at primes where there is a $k$th root of $1$ (those congruent to $1$ mod $k$), it splits as soon as there is one root. Also I just realized that if $a$ or $b$ is $1$ you can't pick a $k$ so that they are not a $k$th power so I need a special case again *sigh*

Comment: This observation is good and I didn't realized it before, but I still wonder why does $a$ have a $k$th root when $b$ have a $k$th root for almost $l \equiv 1 mod k$? And How do we pass from Galois closure to the original $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[k]a)$? Also I think the case when one is 1 is easy, e.g if b=1 then just pick n=0.

Comment: Well, I know why you require k is a prime, this make things easier :)

Comment: Last but not least, if for almost p the property holds, can we show that b=a^n?

Comment: But then $a$ becomes a $p^2$th power, and then so does $b$ etc. Why?
 I know that an element that is an nth power almost everywhere locally but not everywhere locally, see [link]https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grunwald%E2%80%93Wang_theorem

Comment: damnit ! ${}{}$

Comment: Maybe this gap can be fixed？

Comment: Do you have some idea now on how to fix the gap? Anyway, thank you.